# nodemon recursive watch issue?

Tags: node.js, express, nodemon

I have installed nodemon using command:

```
npm install nodemon -g
```

Having done that I changed `"start": "node  ./bin/www"` to `"start": "nodemon  ./bin/www"`

**Output in Console on running   `npm start` :**

```
[nodemon] 1.11.0
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `nodemon  ./bin/www ./bin/www`
[nodemon] 1.11.0
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `nodemon  ./bin/www ./bin/www ./bin/www`
[nodemon] 1.11.0
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `nodemon  ./bin/www ./bin/www ./bin/www ./bin/www`
and so on....
```

Where am I going wrong? Please bear in mind that this is my 3rd day on nodejs so keep it simple.

**Edit**

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon app.js"
  },
```

[image]

[image]

"nodemon app.js" seems to work since the console does not show any errors but then I am unable to run the application. However if I change it back to `node ./bin/www` it would work.

Answer (score 2):

Try to downgrade requirements.
This helped me.

`npm install nodemon@1.0.0 -g`

I reproduced this issue in docker image (node:alpine) with nodemon >1.2.0 100%. And v1.1.0 and v1.2.0 have some strange issues too.

I checked only minor releases (w/o checking patchlevels e.g. 1.2.1, 1.2.2 and others)

So. 1.0.0 is old, but works well.

On my host Mac I have nodemon@1.11.0 installed globally.
Sometimes I have this issue and sometimes I don't. 
This is somehow connected with pwd and nodemon.json file. But I'm not sure.

I found a [bug report](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/933) related to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are watching a file that doesn't exist and this will cause an infinite loop.

In your case, you are running `./bin/www` and looking at you IDE screenshot you have a `./bin/www.js`

That's why `nodemon app.js` doesn't error. Although I can't guaranty it's going to work try `nodemon ./bin/www.js`

Then, without looking at the code, I'm not sure why you can't connect your application that way.

For more info check [@matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3438460/matt) answer and [nodemon docs](https://github.com/remy/nodemon#usage).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to tell `nodemon` what folder to watch. You only need to tell it to run your main application and it will automatically watch all the nested folders and files.

eg. `nodemon app.js` (if app.js is your application)

Also. You can optionally create a `nodemon.json` file in the main body of your application to house config information for nodemon. Not really related to your queestion. But good to have :)

Here is what mine looks like:

```
{
  "ignore": ["data/*.json", "/node_modules/", "README.md"]
}
```

Comment: I changed it to `"start": "nodemon app.js"` , it seems to have fixed the recursion issue since console now says "clean exit -waiting for changes"    but I am not able to connect anymore "This site can’t be reached"

Comment: Edited my question

Comment: What port are you running your application on? Is it possible you messed up what port your trying to view the app on? Also, could you post a pic of your console and what it says when you write: `npm start`?

Comment: I have added the console in my question.

Comment: Clean exit means your application is exiting after running. Do you happen to have a `process.exit(0)` somewhere in your code?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this :

> npm i -D nodemon

in package.json add:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon index.js",
  }
```

This executes the file index.js that is in the root of your app node.
For example:

> app/
>        node_modules
>        index.js

try again:

> npm start